Change outlook region form icon than appers on Ribbon of an Outlook item
I am developing a plugin for Outlook using C# VSTO and add Outlook Region Form.
Form Region Type is Separate
private static void InitializeManifest(Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionManifest manifest, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.Factory factory)
{
    manifest.FormRegionName = "Sender";
}

In this code, I am modifying the text that appears on the ribbon of an Outlook item. But how do I modifying the icon that comes before this text?
